# C# - Limitar valor em TextBox

Tags: c#, textbox

Olá, estou usando C#, e estou com alguns problemas para usar uma TextBox.
Tenho um TextBox com o esse formato: 192.168.100.1, para ser mais especifico estou colocando números de IP. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que a partir do segundo . (100), o número não fosse maior que 255
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar Substring e Length, porém o programa da erro.
Alguém pode me ajudar???

Comment: O projeto é `WebForm` ou `Windows Forms`?

Comment: Estou usando Windows Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sugestão 1**

Recomendo que você use o componente `NumericUpDown`. Inclua quatro deles em seu form e sete as propriedades `minimum` para 0 e `maximum` para 255.

A vantagem de usar esse tipo de componente é que você tem o controle sobre os números que vai receber, além de que, tem a certeza de que só receberá números.

**Sugestão 2**

Use o componente `MaskedTextBox`. Altere a propriedade `mask` para '999.999.999.999' e a propriedade `SkipLiterals` para `false`.

Para verificar o valor digitado, use a função:

```
    public static int verificaValor(string ip, int parte)
    {
//ip é o texto com o ip
//parte é qual das quatro partes você quer verificar
        if (parte == 1)
            return int.Parse(ip.Substring(0, 3));
        if (parte == 2)
            return int.Parse(ip.Substring(4, 3));
        if (parte == 3)
            return int.Parse(ip.Substring(8, 3));
        if (parte == 4)
            return int.Parse(ip.Substring(12, 3));
    }
```

Essa função vai retornar o valor de uma das 4 partes do ip, ex:

Se o ip for `192.168.100.1` e você usar `verificaValor(textBoxIp.text, 3);` será retornado o valor 100.

Assim você pode verificar o valor usando um if:

```
if (verificaValor(textBoxIp.text, 3) > 255)
    //mensagem de erro
```

Mesmo assim, sugiro a primeira forma de fazer, pois evita que o usuário digite valores acima do que você quer.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!
Funcionou certinho, só precisei adaptar ao meu código.
Valeu!!!

Comment: você também pode mostrar sua gratidão dando um like na minha resposta e marcando ela como resposta escolhida (clicando no "confere"). Abraço